# Missing an asssembly reference - 'SingleSignOn' namespace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, single-sign-on, windows-7-x64, claims-based-identity, adfs

I am getting this error when building my project on VS10 on Windows 7:

The type or namespace name 'SingleSignOn' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Just starting learning about ADFS and I am trying to make my web application supports ADFS logons.

Seem like I am missing the SingleSignOn.dll. 
Is it because I am doing this on Windows 7 instead of of a Web server?

Pretty much lost right now.

Answer (score 0):

So I presume you are using WIF?

WIF uses the Microsoft.IdentityModel dll.

Refer [Get Started with Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3487.get-started-with-windows-identity-foundation-wif.aspx)

Or else please provide more detail.